# Parity Error: Account not found for the current chain (Kovan)

Tags: parity, kovan

I am having problem starting Parity with a account that I created using Metamask. This account `0x76Eb17471A5fb78EF6768254D1dAEc528ec6b5a8` has received multiple ETH from Kovan faucets.

Running the following in Windows 10

> parity --chain kovan --unlock 0x76Eb17471A5fb78EF6768254D1dAEc528ec6b5a8 --password password.txt

Gives the error

> Account 76eb…b5a8 not found for the current chain. You can create an account via RPC, UI or `parity account new --chain kovan --keys-path C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys`.

But this account does exist in the Kovan chain! Whats the problem here?

[image]

```
2017-09-17 19:01:01  Starting Parity/v1.7.0-beta-5f2cabd-20170727/x86_64-windows-msvc/rustc1.18.0
2017-09-17 19:01:01  Keys path C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys\Kovan
2017-09-17 19:01:01  DB path C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Parity\Ethereum\chains\kovan\db\9bf388941c25ea98
2017-09-17 19:01:01  Path to dapps C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\dapps
2017-09-17 19:01:01  State DB configuration: fast
2017-09-17 19:01:01  Operating mode: active
Account 76eb…b5a8 not found for the current chain. You can create an account via RPC, UI or `parity account new --chain kovan --keys-path C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys`.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this as well. I think the issue was how I created my account.

I created my account through `parity account new` which defaults to the `ethereum` chain. I had to call `parity account new --chain kovan` instead. Then, I was able to unlock my parity kovan account.

Check and see if your account address shows up when you invoke `parity account list --chain kovan`

Answer (score 0):

why dont you create by code? the sync with chain maybe not quick and correct.

So you can try unlocking the account using the following command:

```
parity --chain kovan --unlock 0x76Eb17471A5fb78EF6768254D1dAEc528ec6b5a8 --private-key <private_key>
```

and normal way is you can also try creating a new account in Parity and transferring the funds from the Metamask account to the new account using these commands:

```
# Create a new account in Parity
parity account new --chain kovan --keys-path C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys

# Transfer funds from the Metamask account to the new account in Parity
parity --chain kovan --from 0x76Eb17471A5fb78EF6768254D1dAEc528ec6b5a8 --to <new_account_address> --value <amount>
```

Remember to replace the placeholders (e.g. `<private_key>`, `<new_account_address>`, `<amount>`) with the actual values for your situation, and to specify the correct path to your keystore directory if it is different from the example provided.

or maybe you can choose hardhat.